# When defining a struct full of members, are these members created for each variable of this struct type?

Tags: c++, c, struct

so there is a code:

```
struct ACDC
{
  double in, out, A, B, C;
};

struct VALUE
{
  struct ACDC I, V;
};

struct VALUE motor1, motor2, DC;
```

When I declare a few variables of this struct like motor1, motor2, DC1, DC2, I don't need to use all the members for all the variables. I only need something like:

```
motor1.I.A; motor1.I.B; motor1.I.C;
motor2.I.A; motor2.I.B; motor2.V.A; motor2.V.B;
DC.I.in;
DC.I.out;
```

So the question is, are the other members declared for the variable and take the space in the memory when I create it? If so, how to do that they're created only when first called?

Thanks

Comment: Sure, if you create variables of type `VALUE`, then memory for the nested structs with all their contents is allocated, regardless of whether you "need" them or not. (OTOH, see @Kiloreux's answer about optimizing compilers potentially doing quite clever dead code elimination tricks)

Comment: It doesn't look like valid C.

Comment: 1) Yes, that's kinda the whole point of having a struct. 2) You can't.

Comment: If your use-case(s) allow mutual exclusive use of any members you could wrap them in a union. Per your examples the `in` and `out` members would be two candidates.

Answer (score 3):

A struct describes a memory layout. When you instantiate one it allocates memory for the whole thing and the member names are essentially mnemonics for the offsets into that allocation, which requires they be known at compile time.

If you want optional elements, you would have to use pointers or possibly some complex template shenanigans over pointers in C++.

Because you specified two very different languages (C vs C++) I can't give a specific, idiomatic example.

However, the example you gave just looks like bad/sloppy design rather than a genuine need for variable optional membership.

You might want to show the problem you are trying to solve as a new question.

Comment: `std::offsetof` would certainly become interesting.

Comment: @user4581301 I suspect the OP is probably familiar with some dynamic/scripting language where objects are basically hashes of properties and name-resolution is done at runtime per instruction.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is **it depends**.

If you use a high-level optimization from the compiler (say -O2 for example) then unless those variable are used somewhere they are going to get canceled by the compiler. Otherwise memory will be allocated for them.

Also about individual `struct` members, Yes, the struct will be allocated as a whole and not by members (check padding also for better understanding).

Comment: Good point. I suppose a clever compiler could completely inline the struct into decomposed variables/registers in some situations, and if it does that, it might even eliminate unnecessary components altogether.

Comment: @Peregring-lk I was specifically talking about variables as a whole, now struct is considered a variable in a whole it's either allocated as a whole or canceled as a whole.

Comment: While this is possible, it would be extremely annoying and dangerous dangerous. It would suck to have an vestigial member in a structure get compiled out and blow the alignment of a read from IO.

Comment: @Kiloreux Sorry, I've erased my comment because the compiler could choose, or at least I can imagine that for a POD struct like the one of the question, and only in some situations, creating different variables corresponding to the used fields instead of a complete object of type struct.

Comment: @user4581301: I don't think destructuring would be done where I/O or taking references is concerned, but it might be useful when you use structs to just pass around the callstack (local variables and function parameters).

Comment: I'd like to see a repo of this. I am unable to reproduce it on any compiler with any settings, and it appears to defy the standard.

Comment: @kfsone what part do you think defy the standard ?

Comment: What I'm worried about is a poorly serialized bit of legacy code that reads/writes POD structures. If one day `char no_longer_used` gets silently compiled out, you have an instant debugging smurfstorm.

Comment: Lets start with 9.2/24´s `Note: The object and its first subobject are pointer-interconvertible`. So there's one element you can't remove.

Comment: @Thilo got me thinking. Say `struct test` has five members. X.cpp uses three members. Y.cpp uses the remaining two. Unless the rules of how files are compiled are radically altered so that the compiler has to know about and handle BOTH compilation units simultaneously X could not call functions in Y and vice-versa because the structure size and offset will be different. This would be pretty bad. Say goodbye to dynamic library linking. This is do-able, but wow. It would take a massive paradigm shift.

Comment: It's one thing for the compiler to eliminate the use of the structure entirely (https://godbolt.org/g/qw57hN) but another for the compiler to use a calculated variant of it. Even using whole-program optimization, I've never seen code produced that modified structure representations, see https://godbolt.org/g/qgsOI5 (elimination) vs https://godbolt.org/g/4E1h7z (preservation). And I've worked in mmo gaming and cloud where optimization is pretty important.

Comment: @user4581301: I don't know about C compilers, but Swift is doing something like this: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2016-01-29-swift-struct-storage.html  Some small and local structs do not make it into memory at all and are kept decomposed into registers. A later optimizer pass could figure out unused function parameters and strip them out. I do agree that this probably does not happen much, but I like the gist of this answer: "exact memory allocation details are not specified by the language and up to the compiler, as long as there is no observable difference".

Comment: I don't think a C compiler is allowed to remove elements from a structure.  In general, it is not safe to do so — all compilation units must agree on the size and shape of the structure.  If the compiler could see the whole program and detect that there was nothing outside that would be influenced by changes to the structure, then maybe something could be done, but I am not aware of C compiler that actually takes such liberties.